# Selenium - How to interact with elements on Iframe

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Im tring to find elements on iframe. But I'm unable to. Here is my code and error I'm getting.

Here is my Script:

```
public class Add_Lists {

    public static void main (String []args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.Chrome_Driver);

        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("http://automation.cloudaccess.host/administrator"); 

        driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-username")).sendKeys("admin");

        driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-password")).sendKeys("admin@123");

        driver.findElement(By.id("mod-login-password")).submit();

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Content")).click();

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Articles"))).build().perform();

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add New Article")).click();

        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Article")).click();

        driver.switchTo().parentFrame();

        driver.siwtchTo.frame(0);

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        WebElement filter = driver.findElement(By.id("filter_search"));

        filter.click();

        filter.sendKeys(Constants.course_Title);
    }

}
```

I have tried adding waits as well but it didn't help. The Iframe opens up post clicking a button and I wish to interact with iframe elements. But when I try to do so, Im getting the below error:

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"filter_search"}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.15.0-24-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'vowellt4', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-24-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276..., userDataDir: /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 66.0.3359.181, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: cd31b3f4a11905c1be0be001fb3154c4
*** Element info: {Using=id, value=filter_search}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:317)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:363)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:309)
    at testScripts.Add_Lists.main(Add_Lists.java:49)
```

Please suggest where its going wrong or how can I get this working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see where you're switching to parent frame, but I cant see where you're switching to the iframe

Comment: @AlexeyR.: I have updated my script. Please have a look.

Comment: In your code there is a spelling mistake like you have mentioned as 
driver.siwtchTo.frame(0);
Please correct it to driver.switchTo().frame(0); and switch to the appropriate frame for locating the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch into correct `iFrame`. use below code :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'administrator/index.php')]")));
```

And just add some pause before that popup get appears. Replace below code in your code and try

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Article")).click();

Thread.sleep(3000);
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'administrator/index.php')]")));
WebElement filter = driver.findElement(By.id("filter_search"));
filter.click();
filter.sendKeys(Constants.course_Title);
```

Its working fine I've checked at my end.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm getting this error: "Expected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: By.xpath: //iframe[contains(@src,'administrator/index.php')] (tried for 20 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)". Can you help me would this happen?