# Java Selenium click checkbox

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I can’t get selenium to click on this checkbox button no matter what I do.

**Error:**

> no such element: Unable to locate element:

I have used sleep thread timers and `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated())`.

**Here is the HTML of the button:**

```html
<input id="1_2_null" type="checkbox" name="1.0.50.gecb16" xgc="" rownumber="1">
```

**I have tried :**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'1_2_null\']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("1.0.50.gecb16")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("1_2_null")).click();
```

**It's possibly inside this iframe:**

```
<iframe frameborder="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="" id="maincontent" name="maincontent"></iframe>
```

Comment: Probably your element is inside `frame` or `iframe`?

Comment: Thank you, how do I check for that?

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='1_2_null']")))

Comment: Using browser dev tools look at the parent nodes starting from your `input` to the root node. Check if one of the nodes is frame or iframe

Comment: Thanks Alexey R.  I belive its inside this
<iframe frameborder="no" width="100%" height="100%" src="" id="maincontent" name="maincontent"></iframe>

Comment: use driver.switchTo().frame("maincontent"); and once your code is done you can swith to main frame using driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium - How to interact with elements on Iframe](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/35001/selenium-how-to-interact-with-elements-on-iframe)

Comment: Thanks Alexey and PDHide, both of you are correct - I think because I am new I cant upvote you both..

Answer (score 0):

**There could be two reasons for that**

1.) your element is not present on the same frame

ii.) the id of the element is dynamic, you can use startswith, endswith or Contains methods of xpath.

**if you can share the Exception, I would be more specific on what might be causing that issue**

Answer (score 0):

If checkbox ID is not dynamic, you can try to have explicit wait for that element's visibility as: 
***element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))***

Here, 10 is the maximum time to wait and you can increase it at max as per your need.